# to write htaccess code for friendly url

Tags: mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I need a help, does anyone can tell me how to change a url

```
"http://www.domain.com/search.php?key=+Ebooks&type=title&Submit=Search"
```

to

```
"http://www.domain.com/keyword- keyword- keyword.html".
```

i have written following htaccess code but its not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule search-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html search.php?key=$1&type=$2&page=$3
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does not work? Is anything happening?

I am not 100% sure but I think you have to do it this way:

```
search-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)\.html search.php?key=$1&type=$2&page=$3
```

Notice the `?` behind the asterisks. It indicates to match a string as *early* as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule search-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html search.php?key=$1&type=$2&page=$3
```